# TKinter button avoid double click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a script that enables a Power supply after the user click "ONLY ONE TIME" the "START TEST" button, right after, I disable the button to avoid the "double click, however, I have noticed that "some how" if user perform a "double click" my application launch a second operation.

```
def starttest():
    Button(main, text="START TEST", font=("Tahoma", 21), height=1, width=24, 
    command=starttest, state=DISABLED).place(x=55,y=40)
    PS = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600, timeout=.1)
    ##my code here ...
```

Does anyone have an idea what should I do to prevent this happen?

Comment: That doesn't look like disabling a button, that looks like creating a new, disabled button on top of the existing one - which is still around to process any queued mouse clicks.  Save a reference to the original button, set its state to DISABLED instead.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `starttest()` function by pressing the inherent button, a new button widget is created: that is why it looks like you are able to click indefinitely on the *falsely* "same" button.

You should create that button somewhere else in your program:

```
...
power_supply_btn = Button(... text="START TEST", command=starttest ...)
power_supply_btn.place(x=55,y=40)
...
```

Then configure the state of that button in your `starttest()` callback using the [`configure()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm) function:

```
def starttest():
   global power_supply_btn
   power_supply_btn.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Thanks @Billal-BEGUERADJ it works, i just have a comment, the command should be:

Comment: def starttest():
           global power_supply_btn
           power_supply_btn.config(state=DISABLED)  ".config instead .configure"

Comment: You are welcome. `config()` and `configure()` do the [same](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm) thing.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works (I apologize for the delay in my reply) my code is working just fine. Thanks all for your help and support.